# Lubuntu 17.10 network manager preventing shutdown

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager, shutdown, atheros

First of all, I am very new to Linux. I recently installed Lubuntu 17.10 in my new Lenovo Ideapad 320.

It hangs on shutdown. If I press esc, I see that it alternates between the two lines

```
A stop job is running for network manager
A stop job is running for WPA supplicant
```

And then there's a timer and after 5 minutes my patience runs out. REISUO does work, but REISUB has the feature that my keyboard doesn't work afterwards (I'm not sure if these things are related).

I've tried `swapoff -a`, which seems to do nothing, `sudo stop network-manager` seems to freeze and `shutdown -P now` and `shutdown -H now` don't do the trick either. I've also tried changing the grub options to `apci=off` or to `apci=force`, neither of which worked.

The kernel version is `4.13.0-16-generic`, and running `lspci -vvnn | grep Network` returns

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/WDZELA4B) are the results of wireless info.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with my ASUS X206HA. 
Updating my linux kernel (4.13.4) to 4.14.0 solved my problem.

I used this guidance:
[ostechnix.com](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-linux-kernel-4-14-lts-rpm-deb-based-systems/)

In the ArchLinux Forum they also discussed a similiar problem:
[archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230604)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly it didn't work for me. For now I've given up and uninstalled it.